# Is signing Java class possible?

Tags: java, jarsigner

I know that we can sign Jar using JarSigner. But, is there any way that we can sign Java class. I searched in google and didn't find anything any where. Can someone help me on this.

I can't make Jar with the classes. And sign. I have a requirement where I need to sign the class.

**Problem Statement:** The error is: Signer Information of one class doesn't match signer information of other classes in the same package.

So, That means, all the classes which are in that package, may go into several Jars after build. So, all those jars to be signed with same keystore.

But, in our case, in our application, we are directly using classes i.e., we are directly loading classes.

And In some other jar there are classes with same package name, which is a signed Jar.

So, the classes which we are directly loading to class loader are unsigned. And the classes with same package name in different jar is signed. So, getting conflict.

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch12_02.htm - You can refer this

Comment: Signing a jar adds additional files into the jar with the signatures of the other files in the jar.   Signing a class will not work, as there is nothing to store the signature in; modifying the class file would corrupt the class.  You could generate a digital signature of the class file, and present that in an additional file.  Or package the class in a jar and sign the jar.

Comment: Please detail how you intend to use the signed class.

Comment: Hi sashwat, AJNeufeld and Krishanthy, thanks for your comments. I updated the question with Problem Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: Direct Signing of a Java class is not possible. We can sign a class only if it is available in some jar.

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR:  Use a different package name for your unsigned classes.]

Signing the jar is establishing a signature authority for each and every package in the jar.  You cannot mix-in new unsigned classes into a package in a signed jar.

If a jar has not been sealed, you can mix-in additional content (classes, resources, ...) into the same package, but these additional classes must come from a jar signed with the same signer information.

Why do we have this restriction?  Java has 4 different access levels: `public`, `private`, `protected` and the default which is "package".  If a signed jar contains a package that has classes/members which are only accessible to other classes in the same package, allowing a new class (unsigned or even signed by a different signer) to be introduced into that package would be ***a glaring security hole***.

If you want these unsigned classes to "plug-in" to your application, the answer is simple.  Put them in a *different package*.  They cannot access package protected classes or methods, so ensure you have a *well defined interface* for these extensions to plug into.